# decoding unicode? im not sure wtf it is

Tags: php, unicode, curl

Im trying to decode some characters that Im getting from a curl call. The strange thing is that on the output it looks ok, but on the source code not, and I cant work with that.

For example:

```
3.200 a. C.

3.200&#xA0;a.&#xA0;C.
```

I have tried everything and I cant find the solution. Please help, thanks!

Comment: &#xA0; is unicode for a non-breaking space. How are escaped entities an issue in your source code?

Comment: Im not sure why is also escaping it on the source code, but try it yourself:

echo '3.200&#xA0;a.&#xA0;C.';

strange!

Answer (score 4):

Those are XML/SGML/HTML character references. [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) should decode them

Answer (score 0):

You can use [multibyte string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php).

Answer (score 0):

`&#xA0` is the character representation of a non-breaking space, i. e. a space where you're not allowed to do a line break. Sort of like `&nbsp;` in HTML.

Where exactly are you running into problems with this?

Comment: im preg_replacing some of the source code, and because of the symbols is impossible to find a normal pattern. what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

The `&#xA0;` is an [XML-escaped non-breaking space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML) (`U+00A0` (160)). <strike>As such, this has nothing to do with Unicode, but ASCII.</strike> (My bad, see comments!)

If you want to "get rid" of it, you should look for a way to decode it, i.e., resolve the XML entities to regular characters.

Comment: The second sentence is completely wrong: ASCII has no code points above 127.  U+00A0 is indeed the Unicode code point for NO-BREAK SPACE. That’s also the same code point in ISO 8859-1.

Comment: @tchrist Oops, thanks for enlightening me :)